# Prove that diagonalization with real entries is not possible when not all eigenvalues are real

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I know that when all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ are real, we have $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$, where the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors and the diagonal entries of $A$ are the corresponding eigenvalues.

However, when not all the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are real (i.e. some of them have imaginary part), is it possible to show that there is no such $P$ and $\Lambda$ where the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ are all real, such that $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$?

Comment: The point is that the diagonal entries **are** the eigenvalues. (And the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is it possible to show that eigendecomposition is the *only* way though?

Comment: Yes. This is because the characteristic polynomial of the diagonal matrix is the same as that of $A$.

Comment: If $AP=P\Lambda$, then $Av_i=\lambda_i v_i$, where $v_i$ is the $i$th column of $P$, and $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th entry on the diagonal of $\Lambda$.

Comment: It depends on which field , we are talking about? On reals , literally a complex value can't be Eigen value as $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $A$ over field of reals iff $Ax=\lambda x $ ,$x$ be vectors with real entries.

Answer (score 0):

Diagonalization w/ real entries$\implies$ all eigenvalues are real.  As pointed out by @Gerry Myerson in the comments, the diagonal entries will be the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ has real eigenvalues and $\Lambda$ has complex diagonal entries. We can write $AP=P\Lambda$. Suppose $P=[p_1 \cdots p_n]$ and $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$. Then, we have
$$
Ap_i = \lambda_i p_i
$$
for all $i=1,2,\dots,n$. That is, $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. But they are the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ which are complex. Therefore, we have a contradiction.

Comment: You need to assume that at least one eigenvalue is complex but not real to get the contradiction.

Comment: Yes, you are right.